# Proper notation for matrix element division

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have two $ n \times n$ matrices, call them $[A]$ and $[B]$, where I want to divide each element by its respective element in the other matrix, what is the proper way to denote that?

I tried to solve for $[A][B]^{-1}$ but $[B]$ is not a singular matrix. Is there a proper way to denote dividing each element at a time?

To clarify, I want to signal the operation to be $A_{i,j} \div B_{i,j}$ where $i,j$ denote the row/column.

Comment: Use the $\div$ symbol (i.e., $A \div B$), but make sure to advise your readers in advance that the $(i,j)$-th entry of $A\div B$ is  $A_{i,j} \div B_{i,j}$. Similarly, for element-wise product of two matrices, you can use the * symbol, but once again, make sure to define your notation in advance. For powers, you can use **.

Answer (score 1):

Your operation is [Hadamard division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)#Analogous_operations).  The notation $A \oslash B$ is used.  But, since it's not very common, you should take quasi's advice and tell your readers what you mean by this.